# Hide keyboard when changing view

Tags: ios, xcode, uitextfield, uitextview

I've already checked other similar questions but none of them solved my problem.
I have a window-based application and I'm using more windows in the same .xib file. In the first window, I have some text fields and I can hide the keyboard tapping on the "Done" button. In the second window I have a text view, and also here by tapping on "Done" the keyboard is dismissed.
The problem is: if I leave the first view without closing the keyboard and I go to the second view, the keyboard is not responding. I can't close it and the button don't work anymore. Where's my mistake? Can I reslove this issue?

I hope you can help me. Thank you so much.

Comment: Do you mean actual distinct `UIWindow`s or are you colloquially referring to different `UIViewController`s?

Comment: I'm using different `UIWindow`s in the same .xib, referring to the same UIViewController.

Comment: You need to be using multiple UIViews in the same window. Not multiple UIWindows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Notification design approach to dismiss the current:

create notification and include it in your cancel method or method that switches to another view:

```
NSNotification *dismissKeyboard = [NSNotification notificationWithName:@"dismissKeyboard" object:nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotification:dismissKeyboard];
```

in your second view add a notification listener in viewDidLoad:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(methodToExecute) name:@"dismissKeyboard" object:nil];
```

add method to execute when notification is sent:

```
-(void)methodToExecute {
    [self.textfield resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to simply resignFirstResponder prior to changing views. Do away with your second UIWindow and use only one UIWindow to swap out views. Normally you use 2 viewControllers and change between them but you can also use 2 different UIViews on a UIWindow if you really wanted.